# Issues With File Sharing on Docker (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, self-hosting, file-sharing

I'm trying to get `vaultwarden` set up and working using `docker`.

I followed the docker install on dockers page and then followed this tutorial for vaultwarden https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_7vJDwGWug.

Everything seems fine when I run the command:

```
docker-compose -d up
```

from the video to run the .yml file that contains:

```
version: "3.9" 
services:   
    vaultwarden:     
        image: vaultwarden/server:latest     
        restart: unless-stopped     
        volumes:       
            - /opt/vw:/data     
        ports:       
            - "80:80"
            - "3012:3012"
```

However, when I run:

```
ls /opt/vw
```

It shows me that nothing has been created within that folder and there should be files created within there.

Doing a bit more digging I checked the docker logs for the container and found some errors. These errors were:

```
[INFO] No .env file found.
 
[2023-03-18 17:07:53.347][vaultwarden::util][ERROR] Can't create 'data/rsa_key.pem': Permission denied
[2023-03-18 17:07:53.347][vaultwarden][ERROR] Error creating keys, exiting...
```

I don't know what's going on with the "No .env file found" but the other errors shows me that it doesn't have high enough permission to create files and folders within the specified volume.

I figured this was an issue with the file sharing as I had read something about it before, so I went to dockers settings, then resources, then file sharing and tried to add the directories (I tried `/opt`, `/`, `/home`, `/opt/vw`, and `/data`) into there so it could access them. I expected this to result in the `vaultwarden` container to have permission to create the files. Unfortunately that did not seem to work as I was still getting errors.

I went to dockers page about how to enable file sharing, https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#how-do-i-enable-file-sharing, to figure out how to file share and this is so far where I've ended up stuck.

I'm at a loss because it seems that the only thing this page tells me is to make sure that `/etc/subgid` and `/etc/subuid` exist and output:

```
MyUser:100000:65536
```

Both `/etc/subgid` and `/etc/subuid` exist and output this when doing:

```
cat /etc/(subgid or subuid)
```

Do I need to maybe change it to have ID 0 where instead it outputs:

```
MyUser:1000:65536
```

Or is there a different ID for root?
Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated as I've spent well over 5 hours trying to fix this one issue.

Comment: Check the permissions on `/data` directory and also the user with which the process is running inside the container. That user doesn't seem to have permissions to write on the directory. You can also do `ls -l` within the container and check what the permissions set on that.

Comment: If you're using docker desktop, you probably want to use relative bind mounts, meaning that some folder on your normal C drive gets mounted into the container rather than the `/opt` folder in the docker desktop wsl installation (trust me, it's painful to get the data out of there)

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav I checked `/data` in the docker container and that requires root permissions which I saw when I used `ls -l`. And I believe the user in the docker container has root permissions as I could create a directory in `/data`. Unless you mean my user outside of docker then I don't know much else besides that I have root access. Also the `/opt/vw` folder requires root access too. If I misunderstood anything just let me know.

Comment: @SIMULATAN So if I understand what you're saying, are you meaning that I make it a different folder than `/opt` and instead maybe go for something like `/home/user/vw` and bind the mount to there? I'm also a bit confused by what you mean by "relative bind mounts", I'm a bit new to all this.

Comment: Well, when using docker desktop, you have to understand that there's a seperate linux file system (wsl) created that is not visible to you as the user. What you instead might want to do is actually bind a folder that is visible directly on your NTFS drive into the container to not have to worry about somehow looking into the WSL file system. In this case, you can use `./data` to specify that the `data` folder in the directory with your compose-file will be mounted into the container.

Comment: @SIMULATAN You definitely seem to be on the right track on what I need to do here. I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but was I not mounting a folder into my docker container with the setup of:
`volumes:       
            - /opt/vw:/data`

Comment: Yes, you were, but that `/opt/vw` folder is in the VFS of Docker Desktop's WSL installation. This file system is separated from the NTFS one of your normal C drive so it can be quite cumbersome to get out the data from there if you ever needed to migrate to some other machine or reinstall your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update the permission of `/opt/vw` to 777 to verify if that works.

```
chmod 777 /opt/vw
```

2. Check the user with which the process is running in the `vaultwarden` container. It is possible that the internal process started by the main script is running by a non-root user that actually doesn't have access to write in the directory.

```
docker top <container-name>
```

3. Update the permissions of the directory based on that user, by updating the entrypoint of the container.

```
entrypoint: 
 - "sh"
 - "-c"
 - "chown <desired-user>:<desired-group> /data && <your-script.sh or whatever you want to run>"
```

Comment: That entrypoint is not going to work - there is no such file named `&&`. You want to run the shell to chain commands. `- sh`  `- -c` `- "chown .... && script ...."`